# fragment shader skips part of coding

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, glsl

hi when i made my fragment shader coding i use:

```
---fragment
$HEADER$
void main(void)
{
    float width = 0.0;
    float offset = 0.1;
    vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
    float coord = normalize(gl_FragCoord.x);
    if (width == 0.0)   {
        vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    else if (mod(((coord+offset) / width),2.0) < 0.3)   {
        vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    gl_FragColor = out_color;
}
```

but when running the file with the vertex shader:

```
---vertex
$HEADER$
void main(void)
{
    vec4 pos = vec4(vPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projection_mat * modelview_mat * pos;
}
```

and the python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import EventLoop
from kivy.graphics import Mesh
from kivy.graphics.instructions import RenderContext
from kivy.uix.widget import Widged
w = 1000
h = 600

class GlslDemo(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = RenderContext(use_parent_projection=True)
        self.canvas.shader.source = 'basic.glsl'

        fmt = ( 
             (b'vPosition', 2, 'float'),
        )

        vertices = (  
             0, 0,
             w, 0,
             w, h,
             0, h,
        )

        indices = (0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0)  

        with self.canvas:
             Mesh(fmt=fmt, mode='triangles', 
                  indices=indices, vertices=vertices)
 class GlslApp(App):
     def build(self):
         EventLoop.ensure_window()
         return GlslDemo()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     GlslApp().run()
```

The problem when running this file is that it just outputs the vec4 out_color and skips the if and if else statements of the fragment shader code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `out_color` is declared 3 times in the fragment shader

1st in the scope of `main`

```
vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
```

And another 2 times in the `if` statement:

```
if (width == 0.0)   {
    vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);
}
else if (mod(((coord+offset) / width),2.0) < 0.3)   {
    vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

You have to assign to the variable which is declared in the scope of `main`, instead of declaring new variables in the `if` statement:

```
vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
if (width == 0.0)   {
    out_color = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);
}
else if (mod(((coord+offset) / width),2.0) < 0.3)   {
    out_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Note, `vec4 out_color;` is a variable declaration, So `vec4 out_color = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);` is an assignment to a new variabel, while `out_color = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);` would assign to the existing variable `out_color`.